# Loop is ignoring to increment the size of the array

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

In the main method below I'm trying to call a sort function and after function selects that latter from the user input it has to print the sort accordingly with the for loop at the end. But I have a warning that reads "loop will run at most once (loop increment never executed)" pointing at the `array[arraySize]`. Does it have to do with the return type or the other for loop above? What's happening here? Can anyone point out and explain please. Thanks much! Here's the code below:

```
int main()
{
    long array[100], arraySize;
    char sort;
    long maxi = 100;

    for(arraySize = 0; arraySize < maxi; arraySize++)
    {
        printf("Enter any positive integer, enter 0 to stop: ");
        scanf("%li", &num);

        if(num < 0) {
            arraySize--;
            printf("I said positive!");
            count++;
        }
        else if(num == 0) {
            maxi = arraySize;
        }
        else {
            array[arraySize]=num;
            arraySize--;
        }
    }

    printf("Please enter A for ascending or D for descending order\n");
    scanf("%s", &sort);

    bubble_sort(array, arraySize, sort); //calling the sort function

    printf(" Sorted list in the selected order:\n");
    for (arraySize = 0; arraySize < num; arraySize++) {
        printf("%ld \n", array[arraySize]);
    puts("");
    return 0;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Thanks everyone for all your suggestions. I did make a few changes and here's what I have so far. Now it's skipping the A/D user input along with the `bubble_sort` function logic. Here's what it does as a final output: Note: `long num` is declared as a global variable!

```
int main()
{
    long array[100], arraySize;
    char sort;
    long maxim = 100;

    for(arraySize = 0; arraySize < maxim; arraySize++)
    {
        printf("Enter any positive integer, enter 0 to stop: ");
        scanf("%li", &num);

        if(num < 0)
        {
            arraySize--;
            printf("I said positive! \n");
            count++;
        }
        else if(num == 0)
        {
            maxim = arraySize;
        }
        else
        {
            array[arraySize]=num; //arraySize--;
        }
    }

    printf("Please enter A for ascending or D for descending order: \n");
    scanf("%c", &sort);

    bubble_sort(array, maxim, sort); //calling the sort function

    printf("Sorted list in the selected order:\n");
    for (arraySize = 0; arraySize < maxim; arraySize++)
    {
        printf("%ld \n", array[arraySize]);
    }
    puts("");
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Output] 
Any more suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: Why you doing `arraySize--` everytime, in that for loop? When exactly `arraySize++` will ever show it's true colours? Won't it always remain on the same state, throughout the loop, except when `num == 0`, since only then the code is not using `arraySize--`. The `else` part should contain only `array[arraySize] = num;` and nothing else, let the `arraySize` increment by 1 after this, so that a new value can be added, at the next index.

Comment: `char sort; .... scanf("%s", &sort);` is bad.

Comment: @nIcEcOw the `arraySize` is so every time I don't have to `arraySize-i` in loop of my `bubbleSort` function!

Comment: @chux how so? Can you explain more why it's bad? It take the input from the user for wether they want ascending descending as a choice.

Comment: @pointing_Stack Agree `scanf("%s",...` will take user input, but it will store the result as a string.  If user types `A`, then `'A'` will get stored in `sort` and `'\0'` will get stored in the next address - who knowns what _that_ will do?  Suggest `scanf(" %c", &sort` instead.

Comment: @chux ohh I see. Typical conversion mistakes I make. Thanks for making it clear :)

Comment: @pointing_Stack  BTW: Best practice: check the results of the `scanf()` family of functions, even when it seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last character entered gets stored in `sort` and that character is most probably `\n`.
Changing `scanf("%c", &sort);` to `scanf(" %c", &sort);` should solve the problem.
Note the space before `%c`.

Comment: this would have never occurred to me. It did indeed solve all the problems I had. Thank you so much! Each of these little mistakes are teaching me something big. :)

Answer (score 3):

There are a few other problems, but let's talk about your warning. You have this code:

```
for (arraySize = 0; arraySize < num; arraySize++) {
    printf("%ld \n", array[arraySize]);
    puts("");
    return 0;
}
```

The corrected indentation should make it obvious why that loop will run at most once.

Comment: I have used this loop in my similar program it works fine. I'm still unsure why it says this warning. Sorry I'm still a beginner.

Comment: @pointing_Stack: Do you understand what your `return 0;` statement means?

Comment: Yes, and I moved it from the scope of this for loop and edited some stuff which I'm adding them now on here.

Answer (score 2):

It seems your print loop has a typo, and should be corrected to:

```
    for (arraySize = 0; arraySize < maxi; arraySize++) {
```

Also the call to bubble_sort() should use maxi rather than arraySize.

Comment: I changed it and it's still not solving a problem.

Comment: Did you make sure to also MOVE the 'return 0' line OUTSIDE of the loop?

Comment: Yes, I did that as well!